# Use SharpDX to capture screenshot of rotated monitor

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

The code below successfully takes screenshots of the monitors attached to my Windows 10 laptop computer, so long as the monitors are not "flipped". When the monitors are flipped to any orientation except "landscape" the captured images are all black pixels (r,g,b,a = 0,0,0,255)

How can I modify the code below so that it will also work with flipped monitors?

Target Framework is:

- Net 4.8

Referenced packages are:

- SharpDX 4.2.0
- SharpDX.Direct2D1 4.2.0
- SharpDX.Direct3D11 4.2.0
- SharpDX.DXGI 4.2.0
- SharpDX.DXGI 4.2.0

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using SharpDX;

namespace ScreenCast {

    internal static class Program {

        [STAThread]
        private static void Main() {
            var captureCount = 0;
            using var factory = new SharpDX.DXGI.Factory4();
            foreach (var adapter in factory.Adapters1) {
                using var device = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device(adapter);
                foreach (var output in adapter.Outputs) {
                    if (output.Description.IsAttachedToDesktop) {
                        var description = output.Description;
                        using var output1 = output.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Output1>();
                        Capture($"{captureCount++}.bmp", device, output1);
                    }
                    output.Dispose();
                }
                adapter.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private static void Capture(string outputFileName, SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device device, SharpDX.DXGI.Output1 output1) {

            int width = output1.Description.DesktopBounds.Right - output1.Description.DesktopBounds.Left;
            int height = output1.Description.DesktopBounds.Bottom - output1.Description.DesktopBounds.Top;

            using var stagingScreenTexture = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D(device, new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2DDescription {
                Width = width,
                Height = height,
                CpuAccessFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.CpuAccessFlags.Read,
                BindFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.BindFlags.None,
                Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
                OptionFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceOptionFlags.None,
                MipLevels = 1,
                ArraySize = 1,
                SampleDescription = { Count = 1, Quality = 0 },
                Usage = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceUsage.Staging
            });

            using var duplicatedOutput = output1.DuplicateOutput(device);

            SharpDX.DXGI.Resource screenResource = null;
            SharpDX.DXGI.OutputDuplicateFrameInformation duplicateFrameInformation;

            AcquireFrame(duplicatedOutput, out duplicateFrameInformation, out screenResource);
            duplicatedOutput.ReleaseFrame();
            AcquireFrame(duplicatedOutput, out duplicateFrameInformation, out screenResource);

            // copy resource into memory that can be accessed by the CPU
            using var screenTexture = screenResource.QueryInterface<SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D>();
            device.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(screenTexture, stagingScreenTexture);

            // Get the desktop capture texture
            var mapSource = device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(stagingScreenTexture, 0, SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapMode.Read, SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapFlags.None);

            using var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            var bmpBounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
            var bmpData = bmp.LockBits(bmpBounds, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
            var src = mapSource.DataPointer;
            var dest = bmpData.Scan0;
            for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                SharpDX.Utilities.CopyMemory(dest, src, width * 4);
                src += mapSource.RowPitch;
                dest += bmpData.Stride;
            }
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            bmp.Save(outputFileName);

            device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(stagingScreenTexture, 0);
            screenResource.Dispose();
            duplicatedOutput.ReleaseFrame();

            // Display the texture using system associated viewer
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, outputFileName)));
        }

        static void AcquireFrame(SharpDX.DXGI.OutputDuplication duplication, out SharpDX.DXGI.OutputDuplicateFrameInformation info, out SharpDX.DXGI.Resource resource) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    duplication.AcquireNextFrame(100, out info, out resource);
                    return;
                } catch (SharpDXException x) {
                    if (x.ResultCode.Code != SharpDX.DXGI.ResultCode.WaitTimeout.Result.Code)
                        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(x).Throw();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot sure you have a reference to the backbuffer of swapchain. There is probability that swapchain has been changed when the monitor has been rotated. So you've lost the reference to the swapchain. Then, maybe you had copied destroyed surface.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

First, I only used SharpDX for a few days, so I'm by no means an expert, but I ran into a similar problem when capturing from rotated monitor and from what I've been able to deduce captured frame is not rotated.

e.g. Your monitor is rotated 90 deg to portrait (Width x Height 1080x1920) so you'd expect the captured frame to be portrait as well, right? Nope, you get the 1920 x 1080 landscape bitmap so your screen width= bitmap height and vice versa:
[image]

Here is the code I used in my capture class, still work in progress:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop;
using Device = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device;
using MapFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapFlags;

namespace EXM.ExampleCapture
{
    public class DXScreenCaptureUtil { 
        private static ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
                            .First(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
        private static EncoderParameters jpegParams = new EncoderParameters() { Param = new[] { new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 60L) } };
        //Cache objects
        private static Factory1 factory = new Factory1();
        private static Adapter adapter;
        private static Device device;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets target device (Display) based on the rectangle we want to capture
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sourceRect">Rectangle we want to capture</param>
        /// <returns>Screen which contains the area we want to capture or null if no device contains our area of interest</returns>
        private static Screen GetTargetScreen(Rectangle sourceRect) {

            foreach (var scr in Screen.AllScreens)
            {
                if (sourceRect.X >= scr.Bounds.X && sourceRect.Y >= scr.Bounds.Y
                    && sourceRect.Right <= scr.Bounds.Width + scr.Bounds.X
                    && sourceRect.Bottom <= scr.Bounds.Height + scr.Bounds.Y
                    )
                {
                    return scr;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static (byte[], int) Capture(Rectangle sourceRect, int jpegQuality) {
            Screen targetScreen = GetTargetScreen(sourceRect);
            if (targetScreen == null) {
                throw new Exception($@"Could not find target screen for capture rectangle {sourceRect}");
            }
            //This is to instruct client receiving the image to rotate it, seems like a reasonable thing to offload it to client and save a bit of CPU time on server
            int rotation = 0;
            byte[] imageBytes = null;
            // Width/Height of desktop to capture
            int width = targetScreen.Bounds.Width;
            int height = targetScreen.Bounds.Height;
            Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(sourceRect.X - targetScreen.Bounds.X, sourceRect.Y - targetScreen.Bounds.Y, sourceRect.Width, sourceRect.Height);

            // Create DXGI Factory1
            if (adapter == null) { adapter = factory.Adapters.Where(x => x.Outputs.Any(o => o.Description.DeviceName == targetScreen.DeviceName)).FirstOrDefault(); }
            // Create device from Adapter
            if (device == null) { device = new Device(adapter); }

            //using (var output = adapter.Outputs.Where(o => o.Description.DeviceName == targetScreen.DeviceName).FirstOrDefault()) //This creates a memory leak!
            Output output = null;
            //I'm open to suggestions here:
            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.GetOutputCount(); i++) {
                output = adapter.GetOutput(i);
                if (output.Description.DeviceName == targetScreen.DeviceName) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    output.Dispose();
                }
            }

            using (var output1 = output.QueryInterface<Output1>()) {
                if (output1.Description.Rotation == DisplayModeRotation.Rotate90) {
                    width = targetScreen.Bounds.Height;
                    height = targetScreen.Bounds.Width;
                    int offsetX = targetScreen.Bounds.X - sourceRect.X;
                    cropRect = new Rectangle(
                        sourceRect.Y - targetScreen.Bounds.Y,
                        targetScreen.Bounds.Width - (sourceRect.Width + offsetX),
                        sourceRect.Height, sourceRect.Width);
                    rotation = 90;
                }
                else if (output1.Description.Rotation == DisplayModeRotation.Rotate270) {
                    width = targetScreen.Bounds.Height;
                    height = targetScreen.Bounds.Width;
                    int offsetY = targetScreen.Bounds.Y - sourceRect.Y;
                    cropRect = new Rectangle(
                        targetScreen.Bounds.Height - (sourceRect.Height + offsetY),
                        targetScreen.Bounds.X - sourceRect.X,
                        sourceRect.Height, sourceRect.Width);
                    rotation = 270;
                }
                else if (output1.Description.Rotation == DisplayModeRotation.Rotate180) {
                    rotation = 180;
                }
            // Create Staging texture CPU-accessible
            var textureDesc = new Texture2DDescription {
                CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read,
                BindFlags = BindFlags.None,
                Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
                Width = width,
                Height = height,
                OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
                MipLevels = 1,
                ArraySize = 1,
                SampleDescription = { Count = 1, Quality = 0 },
                Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging
            };
                using (var screenTexture = new Texture2D(device, textureDesc))
                //Duplicate the output
                using (var duplicatedOutput = output1.DuplicateOutput(device)) {
                    bool captureDone = false;
                    SharpDX.DXGI.Resource screenResource = null;
                    OutputDuplicateFrameInformation duplicateFrameInformation;
                    for (int i = 0; !captureDone; i++) {
                        try {
                            //Try to get duplicated frame within given time
                            duplicatedOutput.AcquireNextFrame(1000, out duplicateFrameInformation, out screenResource);
                            //Ignore first call, this always seems to return a black frame
                            if (i == 0) {
                                screenResource.Dispose();
                                continue;
                            }

                            //copy resource into memory that can be accessed by the CPU
                            using (var screenTexture2D = screenResource.QueryInterface<Texture2D>()) {
                                device.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(screenTexture2D, screenTexture);
                            }
                            //Get the desktop capture texture
                            var mapSource = device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(screenTexture, 0, MapMode.Read, MapFlags.None);
                            var boundsRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
                            //Create Drawing.Bitmap                            
                            using (var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)) {
                                //Copy pixels from screen capture Texture to GDI bitmap
                               var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(boundsRect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
                                var sourcePtr = mapSource.DataPointer;
                                var destinationPtr = bitmapData.Scan0;
                                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                                    //Copy a single line
                                    Utilities.CopyMemory(destinationPtr, sourcePtr, width * 4);
                                    //Advance pointers
                                    sourcePtr = IntPtr.Add(sourcePtr, mapSource.RowPitch);
                                    destinationPtr = IntPtr.Add(destinationPtr, bitmapData.Stride);
                                }

                                //Release source and dest locks
                                bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
                                device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(screenTexture, 0);

                                //Save the output
                                imageBytes = CropBitmapToJPEGBytes(bitmap, cropRect, jpegQuality);
                            }
                            //Capture done
                            captureDone = true;
                        }
                        catch (SharpDXException e) {
                            if (e.ResultCode.Code != SharpDX.DXGI.ResultCode.WaitTimeout.Result.Code) {
                                throw;
                            }
                        }
                        finally {
                            //Dispose manually
                            if (screenResource != null) {
                                screenResource.Dispose();
                            }
                            duplicatedOutput.ReleaseFrame();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            output.Dispose();
            return (imageBytes, rotation);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Crop bitmap
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="orig">Original bitmap</param>
        /// <param name="cropRect">Crop rectangle</param>
        /// <returns>Cropped bitmap</returns>
        static byte[] CropBitmapToJPEGBytes(Bitmap orig, Rectangle cropRect, int jpegQuality) {
            EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, (long)jpegQuality);
            jpegParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
            byte[] imageBytes;
            using (Bitmap nb = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height)) {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(nb)) {
                    g.DrawImage(orig, -cropRect.X, -cropRect.Y);
                    using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream()) {
                        nb.Save(s, jpegCodec, jpegParams);
                        imageBytes = s.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            return imageBytes;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That's a better result than I was able to obtain (I only had all black pixels) can you paste the code you used to get this please?

Comment: This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api#rotating-the-desktop-image seems to confirm my findings, however it does not necessarily explain black image